# how to do padding and windowing function to a non-zero averaged signal which has a zero frequency spectrum

Tags: matlab, padding, windowing

I have a specific question regarding zero padding and windowing function. 
How can I use the zero padding and windowing function to a non-zero averaged signal with zero frequency spectrum in Matlab?

I have a data of my non-zero averaged signal . I am expecting to have a zero-frequency centered spectrum, and also expecting the width of my spectrum changes when I change some parameters in my simulation. The problem is that I want to have more points in the spectrum to build a nice peak. In this case how can I improve my spectrum without increasing the simulation time?
I tried first with blackman windowing and then zero padding without shifting the average to zero. But I do not think this is the right way, as my signal has non-zero average. If I shift the average to zero, I will loose the spectrum at zero frequency.

Comment: Please add a [Minimum Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) / [ask], add your code and the desired output. Then there is a starting point for discussion / help

Comment: I think in this case the question is about the correct way of applying padding, shifting and a window function for a specific type of data and not how to implement it. So an example might be helpful but not necessary for the answer.